# How to authorize an app created using pinterest api?

Tags: php, api, pinterest

I have created a module to pin my images using the Pinterest API as a module in my big PHP application.
Now I am trying to submit the review for my app, which requests the application which I have created.
As it is a heavy application, so I need to upload the entire application file? Or is it okay if I upload only the part which I have created as a separate file?

Someone, please suggest me on how to carry forward.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uploading an actual build of your app is for native mobile apps. For a web app, “uploading” anything makes rather little sense to begin with.

Comment: okay, mine is a web app, will it be okay if i upload only the part of pinning functionality?

Comment: They usually want to see your app _in operation_, for review. For a native mobile app, that of course means you need to get them a simulator build somehow; but for a web app, it makes little sense that you would “upload” it in code form, let alone only parts of it. Go read their documentation of the review process (I can’t, because they require login for that), the proper way to submit your app should be explained in there somewhere. Usually you just need to give them a URL, where they can test your app.